# How to configure to start my application at boot time

Tags: 16.04, boot, startup, services

How to configure to start my application at boot time in Ubuntu 16.04

I am using following files to setup my application as a service.

```
/etc/init.d/myapp
/etc/systemd/systedm/myapp.service
/usr/local/myapp/myapp.sh
```

To start my application at boot time , I have used following command, but it throws error. How can I resolve this issue?

```
sudo update-rc.d paxata-server defaults 
insserv: script paxata-server is not an executable regular file, skipped!
insserv: warning: script 'hst' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

Comment: Why are you using both `/etc/init.d/myapp`, and `/etc/systemd/systedm/myapp.service` files at the same time either use `init scripts` or use `systemd` service files

Comment: @George I don't know which files should be mandatory. I want to start my app using "service myapp start" and start at boot. what are the steps for that.

Answer (score 2):

The old way is `System V` and `UpStart` but the new way is `systemd`. The steps are:

1. Create the service file in `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service`:

   - contents might be (depending on your service needs):

     ```
     [Unit]
     Description=myapp service            

     [Service]
     Type=simple            
     ExecStart=/path/to/myapp.sh            

     [Install]
     WantedBy=multi-user.target
     ```
2. Start it: `sudo systemctl start myapp`
3. Get it to run at boot: `sudo systemctl enable myapp`
4. Other commands of systemctl:

   - stop it: `sudo systemctl stop myapp`
   - disable it: `sudo systemctl disable myapp`

Please see:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: I am getting this error when I execute this -> sudo systemctl enable myapp
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

Comment: Currently I am using service command to start/stop services (e.g.  service paxata-server start). Is there any service command to start my service at boot

Comment: The command was the one you used ealier: `sudo update-rc.d myapp defaults`

Comment: sudo update-rc.d myapp defaults
insserv: script myapp is not an executable regular file, skipped!
insserv: warning: script 'hst' missing LSB tags and overrides

Comment: That's cause it's not setup well use `systemd`

Comment: Tried sudo systemctl enable myapp and sudo update-rc.d myapp defaults. How to start using systemd?

Comment: Now if `sudo systemctl enable myapp` worked do `systemctl status myapp` to check the status, and since I don't know what is in your script you alone should be able to tell if it works as expected...

Comment: I am getting error for both commands 1. sudo systemctl enable myapp 2. sudo update-rc.d myapp defaults. Refer my previous comments.

Comment: Get rid of the myapp file in `/etc/init.d` and use only the one in `/etc/systemd/system`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68866/discussion-between-karan-and-george).

Answer (score 1):

All you need is /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service.

To start: *sudo systemctl start myapp*

To stop: *sudo systemctl stop myapp*

To start at boot: *sudo systemctl enable myapp*